# Unable to create graphs using jp@gc-Graphs Generator in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I want to use jp@gc - Graphs Generator in my Test Plan to create graphs from existing results file(results.csv).

I am getting error - **"Error loading file".**

My results.csv file has data like below:

`14:31:14;1208;login;200;OK;Thread Group 1-2;text;true;950;10;10;1208;1;0;U6021712-TPL-A`

I am not sure how Graphs Generator will be able to create various graphs using the data mentioned above. On checking the error log I noticed below message:

```
2014/12/12 14:31:29 INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: results.csv does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration.

2014/12/12 14:31:29 WARN  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

2014/12/12 14:31:29 WARN  - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: results.csv
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As error message says, you have an error in the definition of timestamp field on the JMeter instance where you run this code.
And configuration differs from the one that led to the CSV file you got.

So you need to check that you use the same jmeter.properties and user.properties on this instance that the one you used on the instance that generated the CSV.

For example here you should have this to fix this issue (but you may have other issues):

- jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

In Jmeter, timeStamp is long datatype. So make sure that no spaces in timeStamp row (If you have a space , jmeter doesn't accept it and throws

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "timeStamp"
```

Example:

Valid data set

```
1456177238234,224,Java Request 1,200,,Auto Quick Invest 1-1,,true,,0,2,2,null,0,1,0,M-SFO1-SFO1216
```

Invalid data set

```
 1456177238234,224,Java Request 1,200,,Auto Quick Invest 1-1,,true,,0,2,2,null,0,1,0,M-SFO1-SFO1216
```

Because timeStamp field has space.